# How to create a String value from Database

Tags: java, database, string

I want to create a string using my database values. as a example, my database contains three fields. such as name, nameId and zip code. and these fields contains abc, 456456 and 11111 values respectively.
now I want to create a string using these values as  ["abc", 456456,11111] using java. how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather odd question, but you can concatenate values in this way to create a string:

```
String myValues = "abc" + "456456" + "11111";
```

Or you can change numbers to String this ways:

```
int myInt = 456456;
Integer.toString(myInt);
```

Comment: @JProgrammer: so, you get these values from the database, and then concatenate them to for a single string from these 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values using a cursor.

```
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("nameId"));
int zip= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("zip"));
```

and then merge it with a Stringbuilder or just

```
String merged = name + " " + id +  " " + zip;
```

You can also concat them in the query with select name || id || zip as merged from userwhatever

Answer (score 0):

Use jdbc to get the desired row from your

> database

to the

> ResulSet

and then concatenate each coloumn value in java code

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad habit doing  string concatenate using String because it create n number of object w.r.t concatenate
better use StringBuffer or StringBuilder depend upon you need Thread safe object or not
below is the example of StringBuffer

```
StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
s.append(resultSet.getString("name"));
s.append(",");
s.append(resultSet.getString("nameId"));
s.append(",");
s.append(resultSet.getString("zipcode"));
System.out.println(s.toString);
```